# How can I make flask link as a directly available web link?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask (in another word, the whole web establishment)

**I want to make the link in Python console as a directly available link in my
desk, so that I can directly open it rather than going to Python and execute flask
file and click the link generated in console.**

Is there anyway I can achieve it? I heard that it maybe something related to

initialize so-called port? Or something?

By the way, the web link back-end database is connected to local MySQL, such web is built

Just for my own use

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

i am new to Flask and Web server, if you have any solution, thanks for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot provided contains the local server and the default port number by which you are able to access the flask URL. In case if you want to access it with any other port you can use the configuration and change the port number.

If the server in which you have your code, is already running, you can run your flask application to run in background.

Other way is to deploy the code in cloud server(Even if for learning purpose). Run the flask application in background and access the URL through the public IP and the port number.

Adding up to this, you can also buy a domain and link your flask URL to this domain and access it from anywhere.